# C#.Net : Edit and Update the dynamically bound grid view

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, .net-3.5, datagrid

In my website I am dynamically binding the datasource to the grid based on the value in dropdownlist.

I want to edit and update the values in grid view and the respective updations should be done in the original database.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the most basic and direct way, you use the `OnUpdateCommand` event of the datagrid to invoke a server site handler. That handler will receive a `DataGridCommandEventArgs` parameter containing an `Item` property which is a grid row with updated values. Retrieve key and new values from that row and build a corresponding update command.

Comment: @mmix: Thanks for the input. In my case the values in the datagrid may be different based on which table is selected in dropdownlist. so how can I write the update statements in OnUpdateCommand? I have as many as 20 options in dropdownlist, each of which represents a different table. What can be done in that case?

Comment: You have to expedite that information too, the easiest I see is to actually check the value in the dropdown while in update event. The server side representation of the dropdown will tell you what option was selected to load the table thereafter you can use the same logic to determine the name of the table to use in update command.

Comment: can you give some small example which will help me understand what exactly you are suggesting me to do?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.onupdatecommand.aspx for event. Inside event you have to determine which table to update, you do that using the same code you used to decide from which table to load the data in the first place (the simplest being `if option1 use table1 elseif option2 use table2, etc, etc.`. Then you build a command for that table. I can't give you an example because I don't know which logic you use to load the table.

Comment: So you mean to say that I should 20 if conditions to check for 20 tables? Will that not degrade the performance?

Comment: Is there a more efficient way of doing this thing?

Comment: well, then you had 20 checks for 20 tables for select command, no? Performance was not your issue then, why now ;)

Comment: as for efficient way, I have not used this approach in ages. The more efficient way is actually to switch to some ajax based solution which will save you from excessive bandwidth usage in roundtrips but if you have N possible sources for an editor (any editor) then yuou have N possible targets for an update from that editor.

Comment: Nope I was just passing the name of the table directly from dropdownlist as my dropdownlist contains my table names. So performance was not an issue then. But here all the 20 tables have different columns so update statements for them will be different and hence 20 checks in that way will be a performance issue.

Comment: Which AJAX based solution are you talking about? Can you throw some light on that?

Comment: Ah, so you use `select * from <dropdown.selectedname>` and let the grid autodetect columns? Well that just gave you the wrong impression that it's easy ;) its not. You can use the table name from dropdown to determine table name, but you will have to "auto-detect" column names from the Item.Cells collection and generate an update SQL script. Something like `UPDATE tablename SET <for each cell in item.cells>: cellColumnName = columnvalue,... WHERE id=item.cells[key].value`. Ajax can help you speed things up but it wont save you from the SQL generation in this scenario

Comment: Yeah exactly I do `select * from <dropdown.selectedItem>` and let gridview autodetect its columns. How can edit delete be done using this approach as I am totally confused on how to proceed?

Comment: Well, I told you in the previous comment, enumerate all columns in the grid (each came from an actual table column) and generate update statement dynamically from that. There is no other way as you don't have a defined data model, but even if you did you would still need branching for each table.

Comment: @mmix: hmm yeah right. Thanks for being so patient and answering my silly questions. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

do you know how to bind dropdownlist vai datasourase?
and witch data sourse you use tell me first.

else you just make a **SELECT query** and **fill** the **dataset** after that you  you must have to bind dropdownlist like this....

```
ds = dropdownlist.DataBind();
```

i think this help you.......
else you can tell me if any problem occure in this code..........

Comment: Yeah I dont have static datasource all I do is create my datasource dynamically based on dropdownlist value. So databinding is not a problem but my problem is how would I know which value is getting updated? because same grid may contain values from different tables based on the value in dropdownlist

Comment: updation in the sense the updation of particular values excluding the primary keys and autogenerate IDs

Comment: when you make SELECCT query at that time it also get row that row have ID you just display that ID in lable so you can find whitch ID is pass....